# Cast uint to Int32

Tags: c#, casting

I'm trying to retrieve data from `MSNdis_CurrentPacketFilter`, my code looks like this:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI",
                "SELECT NdisCurrentPacketFilter FROM MSNdis_CurrentPacketFilter");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
     uint obj = (uint)queryObj["NdisCurrentPacketFilter"];
     Int32 i32 = (Int32)obj;
}
```

As you can see, I'm casting the received object from `NdisCurrentPacketFilter` **twice**, which begs the question: **why**??

If I try to cast it directly to `int`, e.g.:

```
Int32 i32 = (Int32)queryObj["NdisCurrentPacketFilter"];
```

It throws an `InvalidCastException`. Why is that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Three things contribute to this not working for you:

- The type of `NdisCurrentPacketFilter` is `uint`, according to [this link](http://www.scriptinternals.com/new/us/Support/Internal/WMI_MSNdis_CurrentPacketFilter.htm).
- Using the indexer `queryObj["NdisCurrentPacketFilter"]` [returns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementbaseobject.item) an `object`, which in this case is a [boxed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) `uint`, the value of `NdisCurrentPacketFilter`.
- A boxed value type [can only](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx) be unboxed into the same type, i.e. you **must** at least use something like:

  - `(int)(uint)queryObj["NdisCurrentPacketFilter"];` (i.e. a single-line version of what you're already doing), or
  - [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys), which uses [`IConvertible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible) to perform the cast, unboxing it to `uint` first.

---

You can reproduce the same problem as in your question with something like

```
object obj = (uint)12345;
uint unboxedToUint = (uint)obj; // this is fine as we're unboxing to the same type
int unboxedToInt = (int)obj; // this is not fine since the type of the boxed reference type doesn't match the type you're trying to unbox it into
int convertedToInt = Convert.ToInt32(obj); // this is fine
```

Comment: No problem. I found the answer to this when trying to find out why `new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }.Cast<double>().ToList();` throws an `InvalidCastException` - it turned out [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,27bb217a6d5457ec) iterates through the collection using the non-generic `Enumerable` [`CastIterator`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,152b93d25e224365) interface behind the scenes, which boxed the `int` values.